# Can systemctl return an empty code?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Consider the following setting:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet $SERVICE_NAME
STATUS=$?
```

Can it happen under any circumstances that `$STATUS` is then not set or empty? That is, because `systemctl` returns no either empty variable?

Answer (score 1):

Processes do not return environment variables, and they don't return strings – they always return a single integer. Think more in terms of a C function like waitpid(), which has a fixed return type.

There's no way to *not* return it (if you don't, then some garbage value from the stack will be returned, but it *will* be returned anyway), and there is no such thing as "empty" for an int (that would just be zero).

So that means the shell will always be able to put a number in `$?`.